# Moonlight sonata 2-nd movement extra block at the end

Tags: piano

Here is the structure of the [2-nd movement](http://cantorion.org/music/140/Piano-Sonata-No.-14-%22Moonlight%22-Original-version):

```
| Block number |  1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |
| Begin        |  1 |  16 |  36 |  43 |
| End          | 15 |  35 |  42 |  60 |
| Repeated     | no | yes | yes | yes |
```

But [listening to performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Beethoven_Moonlight_2nd_movement.ogg) of the piece I mentioned that after the 4-th block the 1-st and the 2-nd blocks are being played again. So it looks like this:

```
| Block number |  1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |  1 |  2 |
| Begin        |  1 |  16 |  36 |  43 |  1 | 16 |
| End          | 15 |  35 |  42 |  60 | 15 | 35 |
| Repeated     | no | yes | yes | yes | no | no |
```

There is a note "Fine" below the end of the 2-nd block, which means "End". Does this mean that this block must be played at the end of the piece? Is it a notation of jumping between the blocks?

Comment: By any chance does it say 'D.S al Fine' at the end of movement 4?

Comment: @AricFowler No, it says "Alegretto da capo."

Comment: i don't know then...

Comment: The "Allegretto da capo" just means to go back to the start and play Blocks 1-2. I suppose Beethoven could have also written "da capo" or "da capo al fine" (usually abbreviated "D.C. al fine").

Comment: "<movement name> da capo" was the standard convention at that time. "Da capo" on its own could have been interpreted as  "go back to the start of the whole piece, i.e. play the *first* movement again."

Comment: The "standard" modern convention is to omit the repeats in the "Da capo" section, but some musicologists are questioning whether that was the composers' original intention. Certainly there are minuet-and-trio movements where section "1" is much shorter than "2", and not playing the repeat of "1" seems to destroy the balance of the parts. Also there are a few examples where the composer wrote an explicit instruction *not* to play repeats in the "da capo", but (AFAIK) no examples of an explicit instruction that the repeats *should" be played - which suggests that playing repeats was the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this: Block 1, Block 2, Block 2 (repeat), Block 3, Block 3 (repeat), Block 4, Block 4 (repeat), Block 1, Block 2. Cue bats from hell (sorry, I couldn’t resist. The 3rd movement is great.)

I suppose sometimes performers choose to omit some of the inner repeats. But the final two blocks (Blocks 1 & 2) are certainly the end of the piece, not Blocks 3 & 4.

The movement is in the form of a fairly conventional scherzo and trio (like the [Minuet and Trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuet#Minuet_and_trio) form, with the scherzo being in binary form (two related sections, with each section usually repeated)), and the trio in basically the same form. So overall, you have an A-B-A ternary form, with A being the scherzo (first two blocks), B the trio (last two blocks). In this piece, only Block 1 has no inner repeat. And, the reason we don’t repeat Block 2 (i.e. play it a fourth time) the second time around is that you usually do not play the inner repeats during the da capo, but rather play it all the way through to the end.